# SOAP/WCF client accessing a service that uses AWSSDK.dll (Amazon S3)

Tags: c#, wcf, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm encountering something I did not expect.  I have a C# client that accesses a SOAP/WCF service, and the SOAP/WCF service is (trying to) use the AWSSDK.dll to get/put/enumerate objects stored in Amazon S3.  Odd thing is, for some reason, the *client* is getting a FaultException`1 was unhandled with the error text:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK, Version=1.3.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd2d24cd2bace800' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any idea why in the world the *client* would need to have the DLL loaded?  The server hosting the service has it loaded.

In any case, I added the DLL to the client (I have no clue why I would need to, but just for sanity's sake), and lo and behold, even with the DLL added as a reference, I get the exact same error.

Comment: For what it's worth, I also tried setting "copy local" on both the client and the server references (and each combination thereof).  Did not make a difference.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you have a client that you wrote that is calling a service that you also wrote that in turn uses AWSSDK to communicate with Amazon S3?

Comment: Have you verified that AWSSDK.dll is actually in the bin folder of the WCF service?

Comment: Eulerfx - no it was not.  Should I add it to the folder manually in the Visual Studio project and then re-publish?  Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fault exceptions are generated from the service side so that indicates to me that your service is having the problem with the AWSSDK.dll reference. Make sure that your service has the reference to the file and that when you rebuild the dll is in the bin folder of the service startup project.

To build navigate to menu Build -> Batch Build.. -> Select All -> Rebuild.

You should not have to copy the file manually as the build process should copy it to the proper location if you have it referenced.

Another thing would be to check that you are building under the correct configuration. If the dll is x64 and you are running x86 that might also produce the above error (not exactly sure though).